# How to schedule a "egg timer" using Windows Store APIs?

Tags: c#, windows

I need to schedule an "egg timer" (such that an alarm goes off when the timer expires).  I'm neutral to what happens when the timer expires,  if my code runs or just if the user is alerted.

Is there a task for this sort of thing?  I see the MaintenanceTrigger class, but it looks to me like that wont happen on an exact time,  that it's more suitable for downloading web content than knowing when my "egg" is correctly (not raw and not burnt) cooked

Answer (score 1):

You want to use ScheduledToastNotification which, once set, will work even if your app is no longer running. Documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.scheduledtoastnotification.aspx

Guidelines for scheduled notifications are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761464.aspx (also includes links to other docs you'll need to reference)

For a more general overview of the types of notifications you can do on Windows 8, look at this comparison http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779721.aspx

Comment: @stuck go ahead and click the checkmark to accept this as your answer if it's what you were looking for